# Windows 2012 R2 Cluster

Tags: windows, cluster, rpc

This is my first time building a Failover Cluster.

I run the validation and every time I get the following.
"Failed to prepare storage for testing on node {SERVER NAME}: The remote procedure call failed."

The Server Name is always the same no matter which server I run the Failover from.

Steps I have done to troubleshoot
 1. Disabled Firewall
 2. Check RPC Services
 3. Make sure all drives were assigned a drive letter and all drives not in use were disabeld

Does anyone else what an idea?

Answer (score 0):

What do your system have ? 
Did you verify prerequisites with Microsoft Cluster requirement ?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn505754.aspx#BKMK_ClusPrereq

Comment: Yes. Even got microsoft on the phone and they were a stuck. So we working with Cisco now seeing if its a UTS issue.